# Superpowered SDK Android

Tags: java, android, c++

Hello i want to create a player with superpowered sdk but i can't exit from loop. When the song ends, he starts playing again, as it removed?

> С++ void for start and pause playing;

```
void SuperpoweredExample::onPlayPause(bool play) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
if (!play) {
    playerA->pause();
    playerB->pause();
} else {
    bool masterIsA = (crossValue <= 0.5f);
    playerA->play(!masterIsA);
    playerB->play(masterIsA);
};
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

> This void in JAVA

```
public void SuperpoweredExample_PlayPause(View button) {  // Play/pause.
    playing = !playing;
    onPlayPause(playing);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playPause);
    b.setText(playing ? "Pause" : "Play");
}
```

> And player initialize and play options in C++

```
SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer *playerA = *((SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer **)clientData);
    playerA->setBpm(126.0f);
    playerA->setFirstBeatMs(1);
    playerA->setPosition(playerA->firstBeatMs, false, false);
    playerA->exitLoop(); // not work
    playerA->looping = false; // not work
    playerA->togglePlayback();

    playerA = new SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer(&playerA , playerEventCallbackA, samplerate, 0);
    playerA->open(path, params[0], params[1]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handle playback state in your method *playerEventCallbackA* from

```
playerA = new SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer(&playerA , playerEventCallbackA, samplerate, 0);
```

It is the callback for main player events.
If you look at *SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer.h* class you will find

```
typedef enum SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent {
    SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_LoadSuccess,
    SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_LoadError,
    SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_EOF,
    SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_JogParameter,
    SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_DurationChanged,
} SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent;
```

And when you receive *SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_EOF* event you can pause or do whatever you want with playback.

E.g.

```
    static void playerEventCallbackA(void *clientData, SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent event, void *value) {
        SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer *playerA = *((SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer **)clientData);
        if (event == SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_LoadSuccess) {
            // handle player prepared
        } else if (event == SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_LoadError) {
            // handle error with player
        } else if (event == SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_EOF && !loopingA) {
            playerA->pause();
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: OOO MEN, BIG THANKS!